# Server Side Event - onmessage not firing

Tags: javascript, server-sent-events

I'm trying to consume sse response in javascript. The onopen and onerror works well but onmessage not.

```
var conn = new EventSource(`${config.serverHost}/log/stream/${this.streamId}`)
conn.onopen = (evt) => {
    console.log('connected to ' + logSourceId)
}
conn.onmessage = (evt) => {
    console.log(evt)
}
conn.onerror = (evt) => {
    console.error(evt)
}
```

[image]

Connection establishes successfully and events received can be found in Chrome Network Recording as following image shown. But onmessage is never triggered!

[image]

Any comment will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You appear to be using named events (something along the lines of *"log streami..."*).

To support these, you need to use the `addEventListener` format.

```js
// assuming the event name is "log streaming"
conn.addEventListener("log streaming", e => {
  console.log("log streaming", e)
})
```

FYI, `onmessage` is for any un-named events, aka those [event streams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events#fields) without an `event` property.

> **event**
>
> A string identifying the type of event described. If this is specified, an event will be dispatched on the browser to the listener for the specified event name; the website source code should use `addEventListener()` to listen for named events. The `onmessage` handler is called if no event name is specified for a message.