# How to get Event Source working in React?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, server-sent-events

I have been experimenting trying to get data from the server in real time using the EventSource. Here is my server code and my react code:

REACT:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchQuestion();
    const eventSource = new EventSource(`${BaseURL}quiz/realtime-questions`);
    eventSource.onmessage = (e) => { console.log(`got this data ${e.data}`); updateQuestion(e.data)};
    return () => {
      eventSource.close();
    };
  }, []);
```

NODEJS:

```
quizRoute.get("/realtime-questions", (req, res) => {

    console.log(`request made to realtime-questions`);

    res.writeHead(200, {
        "Connection": "keep-alive",
        "Content-Type": "text/event-stream",
        "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    });

    setInterval(() => {

        console.log('requested received');
        res.write('event: message\n');
        res.write(
        "data:" + "some data"
        );

        res.write("\\n\\n");
    }, 10000);
});
```

I have checked and make sure that the server receives the request and that it starts sending the data over the response. However I am not receiving any data in my react client.

Comment: Can you see the data coming in using your browser dev-tools?

Comment: Since you're using named events (named `message`), you may need to use `eventSource.addEventListener("message", ...)` instead. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68811568/283366)

Comment: Yes, I have confirmed that the server is sending data, however I am not receiving on the client. And I have also tried adding an event listener on the eventSource but it didn't work.